# Break a statement (expression) into multiple lines: how to indent

Tags: f#, indentation

I found it's very hard to search for the simple indentation guide in F#.
Basically, I am wondering what's the rule for multiple-line statement indentation.
In C#, there is no problem because whitespace doesn't count.
Although I can write F# code according to my intuition and it works, I really want to know what's the rule for breaking one statement into multiple lines.
I write as

```
printfn "%d"
    1
```

It works as expected

And if I write them in the same column, something goes wrong.

```
>
printfn "%A%A"
1
[];;
> //nothing is returned... and no error in this case
```

I want to confirm the basic rule for doing this. It's a little annoying when you can't be sure what you are doing.

Thanks in advance

I just tried another case

```
List.iter
    (printfn "%d")
        [1..10];;
```

And it prints out 1 to 10.
Why it's not

```
List.iter
    ((printfn "%d")
        [1..10]);;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Yin points out, the rule is that arguments of a function should be indented further than the call to the function. To add more details, your first snippet is interpreted like this:

```
printfn "%A%A";
1;
[];
```

Each of these is a valid expression that returns something (function, number, empty list) and then ignores the result and continues. Because they are written in the top-level scope, F# Interactive doesn't emit a warning that you're ignoring some values. If they were in a `do` block or `let` declaration:

```
do
  printfn "%A%A"
  1
  []
```

The F# compiler would emit a warning when sequencing expressions (using `;`) that do not return `unit`:

> stdin(5,3): warning FS0193: This expression is a function value, i.e. is missing arguments. Its type is 'a -> 'b -> unit.
>
> stdin(6,3): warning FS0020: This expression should have type 'unit', but has typ
>   e 'int'. Use 'ignore' to discard the result of the expression, or 'let' to bind
>   the result to a name.
>
> stdin(5,3): warning FS0020: This expression should have type 'unit', but has typ
>   e ''a list'. Use 'ignore' to discard the result of the expression, or 'let' to b
>   ind the result to a name.

Comment: But in the previous case, it should return val it: 'a -> 'b -> unit, val it: int = 1, val it: 'a list = []

Answer (score 4):

In your second example, you should indent:

```
>
printfn "%A%A"
  1
  [];;
```

Otherwise the three expressions are three sequential expressions, not a single expression.

You can refer [F# Language Specification](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=79948) for firm rules, e.g. Chapter 15 in the specification.

Comment: I couldn't find the specific rule for breaking a single statement. Maybe I can read it more carefully when I have time. But I don't think it's inside the specification.